# Графический редактор, позволяющий рисовать растушеванной кистью

Tags: delphi

Вот мой вариант: имеется область рисования `image2`, и `image1` с bitmap'ом растушеванной кисти. По событию `OnMove` на `image2` рисуется растушеванная кисть. Буфер `bmp` (тип `tbitmap`).

**Проблема в том, что рисуется медленно**

Вот код:

```
procedure TForm1.Image2MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);

begin

bmp:=image2.Picture.Bitmap;

for i:=1 to 99 do

for j:=1 to 99 do begin

alpha:=round(getrvalue(image1.Picture.Bitmap.Canvas.Pixels[i,j])/255*100);

bmp.Canvas.Pixels[i+x,j+y]:=rgb(

round(getrvalue(image2.Picture.Bitmap.Canvas.Pixels[i+x,j+y])*(alpha/100)),

round(getgvalue(image2.Picture.Bitmap.Canvas.Pixels[i+x,j+y])*(alpha/100)),

round(getbvalue(image2.Picture.Bitmap.Canvas.Pixels[i+x,j+y])*(alpha/100))

);

    end;

   image2.Picture.Bitmap:=bmp;

end;
```

Может, если писать на winapi, то поможет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При таком подходе, даже если писать на АПИ, то выиграете пару процентов. Но есть способ который может дать ускорение в несколько раз, а то и в десяток.

Итак, рисуем картинку не на экран сразу, а в памяти, на TBitmap. Те же самые операции, но битмапе в памяти. Его размеры делаем равным размерам картинки. Все бы хорошо, но саму картинку хочется видеть, а не рисовать в слепую. Поэтому, TImage заменяем на TPaintBox, который заметно лучше подходит для прорисовки и находим у него событие OnPaint, где пишем код в одну строку, который будет прорисовывать TBitmap с памяти на компонент (метод Draw).

И последняя мелочь. В коде, который рисует на битмапе, должен вызывать метод invalidate у бокса, что бы он обновлялся. Если код обработки сложный, то можно отрисовку вызывать по таймеру (конечно, сделав синхронизацию).
Посмотреть пример кода можно [здесь](http://home.hccnet.nl/david.dirkse/math/dynapaint/smoothdraw.html).